# mDNSResponder compilation on MinGW

Tags: windows, mingw, mdns

I am trying to build mDNSResponder on MinGW for a very important project.  I have MinGW installed and I've downloaded the latest version of mDNSResponder from Apple's site.   There doesn't seem to be any way to build for MinGW.  Also, it appears to require pthreads in order to build

I also found the Bonjour SDK, but it seems like it only has MSVC compatible libraries in it and when I try to use reimp in MinGW to convert them to DLLs I get the "invalid or corrupt library" error back.  Presumably this is because MS changes it's name mangling scheme on occasion.

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Greg

Comment: If these are C++ libraries, and they are not open-source, then you're screwed, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but, with respect, you're incorrect.  mDNSResponder is open sourced by Apple.  I'm simply wondering if anyone has either built the sources using MinGW or been able to convert the existing lib using MinGW's tools used for that specific purpose.

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted my comment. I didn't make any claims as I don't know this library, in fact, I was saying that if it's not open-sourced and it's C++, then you would have been out of luck. Anyway, since you say that it's open-source, then what stops you from building it with MinGW from source? The question as it stands now is impossible to answer. I have to know the exact troubles you are facing. Notice that conversion of C++ libraries will of course never reliably work for you.

Comment: Nothing, the nature of my question was that I was wondering if anyone had done it so I could use what they did.  As it stands I was unable to find anything.  It seems obvious that I'm going to need to combine the mDNSPosix and mDNSWin32 implementations of this library together to make a working "mDNSMingW" version.  If you look at the source for the library you will understand what I'm referring to.